# C# only writed last string

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a problem, I am writing some data to file save.txt, but in file is only last item which I write.

This is my code:

```
SetLine("save.txt", Obchod.numbers[0].ToString(), 5);
SetLine("save.txt", Obchod.numbers[1].ToString(), 6);
SetLine("save.txt", Obchod.numbers[2].ToString(), 7);
SetLine("save.txt", Obchod.numbers[3].ToString(), 8);
SetLine("save.txt", Obchod.numbers[4].ToString(), 9);
SetLine("save.txt", Obchod.numbers[5].ToString(), 10);
SetLine("save.txt", Obchod.numbers[6].ToString(), 11); `

void SetLine(string filename, string text, int linenumber)
{
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@filename, false))
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < linenumber; i++)
      {

      }

      sw.WriteLine(text);
      sw.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: The for loop, but they are wrong - the loop is irrelevant

Comment: @Dortik: You only have one loop.

Comment: Simply change `new StreamWriter(@filename, false)` to `new StreamWriter(@filename, true)`. The second argument specifies that the writer should _append_ to the file instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @DStanley There isnt mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing and reopening the file between each write.  Either keep it open or specify a parameter to append to it instead of overwriting (which is default)

Comment: Acutally, the default does not matter, because he is explicitly passing `false` in to the append parameter.

Comment: Ah - I don't know StreamWriter params off the top of my head so hadn't realised that was the append option!

Comment: Not a very well explained answer in my opinion. Should provide example solution at least

Comment: @musefan Fair enough comment - I will bear in mind in future.  Not much point in editing now though as there is another answer

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `false` to the [`StreamWriter`-constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) which tells it to not append the text to the file but to overwrite the whole text.

I guess you want to rewrite a textfile and the last parameter indicates which line should be overwritten. Then this should do it:

```
public static void ReplaceLine(string filename, string text, int linenumber)
{
    string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    if (allLines.Length < linenumber)
        return; // or ArgumentException?
    allLines[linenumber - 1] = text;
    File.WriteAllLines(filename, allLines);
}
```

But note that it's not efficient to use this method in a loop since it will always load the file into memory, replaces one line and rewrites the whole file.